# How can angular 2+ app hosting In nesuit server?

Tags: netsuite

Currently I'm working project that back-end is based on oracle netsuit erp. I want to create frond-end using angular 2+ framework and host it withing the netsuit server. Is there any solution to that scenario or I just have to use RESTlets and create front-end separately and host it another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create your angular SPA as an html file
- in that angular app, talk to netsuite using the http client and thru a suitelet, NOT a restlet. this gets you around CORS
- upload that file to the cabinet
- create the "render" suitelet that will load the HTML file into netsuite's templateRenderer module (ex: `var html = angularSrcHtml.renderAsString();`)

Comment: Thank man I will check it and if it work I will accept the answer.

Comment: sclearion whats about js bundle. where should i put them?.

Comment: you could 
- include them as modules and use with a client script
- host them in the cabinet after making them public. 

both approaches have worked for us

Comment: sclearion if i want to use angular app only as e commerce web site still same setup work?.

Comment: I do not think it will work unless you are specifically calling that suitelet that renders your angular app

Comment: I have created the app and build the app and use hosted files integration and put the build file into live hosting folder in the file cabinet. then select home page as hosted file and the path to the index file it shows angular app when go to preview. Can i use suitlets to get information from netsuits from there?

Comment: Yes. It gets you around CORS or you could inject it with render.DataSource. Its up to you

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same, do you have any GitHub repository to explain the process in detail, how were you able to create one HTML file that contains all Angular application? please provide me any link that could help me to achieve that?

Comment: I'm running into CORS issues. How do you get around this again? Not following on that part.